# Gulp isn't running right

Tags: javascript, gulp, wiredep, gulp-inject

I have this tasks:

- html:

  - transform .jade in .html
  - copy bower resources (css, js and fonts) to /dest/vendor folder
  - add bower resources to .html (script and link tags)
  - add my js (from /dest/js) and my css (from /dest/css) to .html (like prev.)
- build

  - clean /dest folder
  - copy my js to /dest/js (just copy, no process)
  - process my less files, and move to /dest/css as css

if I run `gulp build` and then `gulp html`, everything works fine. But, if a add `html` as build last part, don't work more.
Jade is transformed in a .html file, a all resources (my and bower) are copied to /dest folder, but `wiredep` and `inject` (that add script and link tags) appears do nothing.

This is (a part of) my tasks: https://gist.github.com/Falci/f52d4144318c9d5e4c2f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple potential issues with your build.

1. You must **return the stream** from each task. Gulp relies on the return value of each task to determine when that task is finished. If you use a task without a return value as a dependency of another task, the dependency will be resolved immediately instead of waiting for the task to finish. You should use return values instead of using the `next()` callback.

   ```
   function htmlAssetsTask () {
       var sources = gulp.src(config.filesets.assetsDest, {read: false});
       return gulp.src(config.filesets.html)
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Gulp task dependencies **are not run in order**. This means that in the task:

   ```
   gulp.task('build', ['clean:dest', 'build:js', 'build:less', 'html']);
   ```

   the dependencies can run in any order. I suggest using the [run-sequence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence) package to ensure the order of task dependencies when it is important.